# How can I properly use pivot on this pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following df:

```
Item  Service    Damage    Type          Price
A      Fast       3.5         1          15.48403728
A      Slow       3.5         1          17.41954194
B      Fast        5          1          19.3550466
B      Slow        5          1          21.29055126
C      Fast       5.5         1          23.22605592
and so on
```

I want to turn this into this format:

```
Item  Damage  Type   Price_Fast Price_slow
```

So the first row would be:

```
Item    Damage     Type    Price_Fast    Price_slow
A        3.5         1        15.4840..     17.41954...
```

I tried:

```
df.pivot(index=['Item', 'Damage', 'Type'],columns='Service', values='Price')
```

but it threw this error:

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 2340, index implies 3
```

Comment: Try `df.pivot_table(index=['Item', 'Damage', 'Type'],columns='Service', values='Price')`

Comment: Repeat? Like `df.columns = "Price_" + df.columns` after you pivot? I'm not sure what you mean by repeat.

Answer (score 2):

To get exactly the dataframe layout you want use

`dfData = dfRaw.pivot_table(index=['Item', 'Damage', 'Type'],columns='Service', values='Price')`

like @CJR suggested followed by

`dfData.reset_index(inplace=True)`

to flatten dataframe and

`dfData.rename(columns={'Fast': 'Price_fast'}, inplace=True)
dfData.rename(columns={'Slow': 'Price_slow'}, inplace=True)`

to get your desired column names.

Then use

`dfNew.columns = dfNew.columns.values`

to get rid of custom index label and your are done (Thanks to @Akaisteph7 for pointing that out that I was not quite done with my previous solution.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following code:

```
# You should use pivot_table as it handles multiple column pivoting and duplicates aggregation
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['Item', 'Damage', 'Type'], columns='Service', values='Price')
# Make the pivot indexes back into columns
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
# Change the columns' names
df2.rename(columns=lambda x: "Price_"+x if x in ["Fast", "Slow"] else x, inplace=True)
# Remove the unneeded column Index name
df2.columns = df2.columns.values
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  Item  Damage  Type  Price_Fast  Price_Slow
0    A     3.5     1   15.484037   17.419542
1    B     5.0     1   19.355047   21.290551
2    C     5.5     1   23.226056         NaN
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the answer @sphexoo gave 20 minutes earlier.

Comment: @MichaelD Not quite, it has explanations and an extra, necessary, step at the end. I would be happy to remove mine if he includes those. I posted my code because it is more complete so far.